# Sliding parallax background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

I have recently worked on a site that is effectively a series of long scrolling pages. It has some large background images the make use of a parallax effect as well as some carousels and regular text content. I am using [slick] by ken wheeler for the carousels. [1](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) I [Live demo site here](http://dev.searsdavies.co.uk/castlebrooke/demo/option1/manchester.html)

My question is, is anyone aware of a way to create a carousel of large images (like the one pictured below)that also makes use of a parallax effect? the effect is currently achieved using the Parallax.js plugin (http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) but I am open to other plugins/approaches. Thanks in advance for any ideas or pointers in the right direction.

Screenshot of current carousel that I wish to add parallax effect scrolling to:
[image: Screenshot of current carousel that I wish to add parallax effect scrolling to]

*edit:  I have tried creating multiple slides within the carousel using the parallax.js method to add a background image. However this just keeps the first image used as a constant background and does not slide off screen when the arrow is clicked

Comment: @Pogrindis I have tried creating multiple slides within the carousel using the parallax.js method to add a background image. However this just keeps the first image used as a constant background and does not slide off screen when the arrow is clicked

Comment: What slider plugin are you using ?

Comment: @andyjones slick by ken wheeler, but also open to using a different sliding plugin

Comment: Cool, looks like it isn't a problem with slick, what pixelcog seems to do is take the attributes and build extra elements in the dom. New sections which it then assigns height and moves the background with, you would either need to rewrite pixelcog or you need to find a new parallax plugin. Scrollarama 2 is a good one. - http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Comment: @andyjones will investigate scrollarama 2 and see how I get on